# How does AzureSignTool Works internally

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I was debugging azuresigntool code and found it retrieves the public certificate from azure key vault and do the signing.
I want to know does it use private key for signing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/sign-with-akv-cert), AzureSignTool uses both public and private keys from Azure Key vault to sign-in.

Please **note** that:

> **To ensure best security practices, your private keys for distribution should be handled only by the tooling recommended by your Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment (CI/CD) platform.**

- If you use private key for signing in, make sure **not to expose** them.
- If your private key is compromised then anyone can reuse and sign in with your identity.
- The files specified must be public certificates only as mentioned in this [***Github***](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool#azure-sign-tool) blog by Kevin Jones.

You can **refer** the below blog by Matteo Pagani for more details:

[Signing a MSIX package with Azure Key Vault - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/signing-a-msix-package-with-azure-key-vault/ba-p/1436154)